# What's the fastest way to make soft body and/or cloth interact at a fixed position with a rigid object?

Tags: animation, physics

I'm just trying to get this physics to work at all.

I have a plane I subdivided like 15 times, so it should have enough verts to render something. I then made all edge vertices as a pin vertex group with a weight of 1.00 and all  inner vertices with a weight of .98 and set those vertex groups as the mass and goal in the soft body physics tab for the plane.

I then tried animating a basic materialed cube moving into the plane, and it wouldn't render the collision. Blender rendered the plane's self-deformation, how it sags in the middle, but no matter what I do, it refuses to render a basic collision with this rigid object.

I got it to work for the cloth settings by setting the rigid object as a collision object, but it still doesn't work for soft body.

Comment: what's the question? what are you trying to do? (not so clear from your post)

Comment: Get soft-body to detect the collision and thus deform as a result of a generic rigid object, as indicated.

Comment: Wow I did not think such a basic question would be unanswerable. People here...know what soft body physics is right?